# Can I get the TargetOutputs of an MSBuild task in a Rake/Albacore script?

Tags: msbuild, rake, albacore

MSBuild can provide the list of project output if you define an `Output` element like below

```
  <MSBuild Projects="YourSln.sln">
      <Output ItemName="YourProjectOutputs" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
  </MSBuild>
```

Can I get that list with Rake/Albacore?

Comment: Can you provide a working `.targets` file or full command line representation so that I can see the output you get with this task?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any way to provide an `Output` parameter to MSBuild on the command line, except through a `.csproj` or `.target` file. So, I don't think it's something we can fix by introducing more features on the Albacore msbuild task (which just invokes msbuild in the shell).

You can still get the list of project/solution output using regular Ruby/Rake. It's not perfect, but start with a single msbuild `OutputPath`

```
msbuild :msbuild do |msb|
  msb.solution = 'YourSln.sln'
  msb.properties :configuration => :Debug, :outputpath => './bin/Debug'
  msb.targets = [ :Clean, :Build ]
end
```

And define a [`FileList`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) that takes in all the items from that directory (and sub-directories)

```
msbuild_output = FileList['./bin/Debug/**/*']
```

You could define just `.exe` or `.dll` files, but you wouldn't know if they were actually msbuild output or post-build copy events or content or whatever. That's the downside.